# Node.js module level variables are undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, scope

I'm having an issue accessing the scope of a module level variable from within a function inside of said module. See below...

```
var socketio = require('socket.io');
var socket = socketio.listen();

var myCustomModule = require('./lib/mycustommodule')('http://mysite:8080');

socket.on('connection', function connection(socket) {

    socket.emit('message', {data:"test1"});  <====THIS WORKS

    socket.on('init', function init(data) {

        socket.emit('message', {data:"test1"});  <====THIS WORKS

        refreshMyCustomModule();
    });

});

var refreshMyCustomModule = function() {

    socket.emit('message', {data:"test1"}); <=====THIS DOESN'T WORK

    myCustomModule.beginSomeAsyncTask(function(data) { <======THIS DOESN'T WORK

         socket.emit('message', {data:"test2"}); <========THIS DOESN'T WORK

    });

};
```

Looking at the sample above. When I call my refreshMyCustomModule function suddenly `socket` and `myCustomModule` become undefined. I've also tried using this as well as setting up a `var self = this`.

I've written a bunch in javascript on the client but when coding in node.js it seems like scoping is different and I just can't crack this nut.

Comment: The scope rules are identical. JavaScript, the *language*, defines the scope rules. NodeJS and browsers, the *environment*, do not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you're using an async event in socket.on('init') that leads to the scope issue.  I believe if you pass in the parameters you want to use from the parent it will work.  e.g.:

```
var socketio = require('socket.io');
var socket = socketio.listen();

var myCustomModule = require('./lib/mycustommodule')('http://mysite:8080');

socket.on('connection', function connection(socket) {
    socket.emit('message', {data:"test1"});  <====THIS WORKS

    socket.on('init', function init(data) {

        socket.emit('message', {data:"test1"});  <====THIS WORKS

        refreshMyCustomModule(socket, myCustomModule);
    });

});

var refreshMyCustomModule = function(socket, module) {

    socket.emit('message', {data:"test1"}); <=====THIS DOESN'T WORK

    module.beginSomeAsyncTask(function(data) { <======THIS DOESN'T WORK

         socket.emit('message', {data:"test2"}); <========THIS DOESN'T WORK

    });

};
```

Answer (score 3):

Note that the `socket` at the global level of your script and `socket` within your `function connection` **are two different variables**. The one inside your `function connection` is the *argument* that was passed into that function from the connection event. The one you're using in `refreshMyCustomModule` is the global one, the one on which you called `listen`.

This is clearer if we change their names, since they're different variables:

```
var socketio = require('socket.io');
var socketUsedForListen = socketio.listen();

var myCustomModule = require('./lib/mycustommodule')('http://mysite:8080');

socketUsedForListen.on('connection', function connection(socketFromConnection) {

    socketFromConnection.emit('message', {data:"test1"});

    socketFromConnection.on('init', function init(data) {

        socketFromConnection.emit('message', {data:"test1"});

        refreshMyCustomModule();
    });

});

var refreshMyCustomModule = function() {

    socketUsedForListen.emit('message', {data:"test1"});

    myCustomModule.beginSomeAsyncTask(function(data) {

         socketUsedForListen.emit('message', {data:"test2"});

    });

};
```

I'm reasonably certain you *meant* to use `socketFromConnection` in `refreshMyCustomModule`, not `socketUsedForListen`. If so, either move the `refreshMyCustomModule` *into* your connection callback, or pass the socket into it as an argument.

Comment: +1 @T.J. Crowder , this helped me understand why my socket variable was not correct. Thank you. I totally missed that.